# HTTP 405 method not allowed, seems to be a CORS issue

Tags: javascript, ajax, printing, cors

Requested this URL from my Javascript program (has library `epson-2.6.0.js`, epson sdk for javascript for thermal printers). I am targeting a TM U220 over ethernet.

```
GET XHR http://192.168.199.15:8008/socket.io/1/

OPTIONS XHR http://192.168.199.15/cgi-bin/epos/service.cgi   [HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed 7ms]
```

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://192.168.199.15/cgi-bin/epos/service.cgi?devid=local_printer&timeout=10000. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

**Response headers (118 B)**

```
Allow   GET, HEAD, POST
Content-Length  0
Server  Allegro-Software-RomPager/4.01
```

**Request headers (478 B)**

```
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xm…plication/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en
Access-Control-Request-Headers  content-type,if-modified-since,soapaction
Access-Control-Request-Method   POST
Connection  keep-alive
DNT 1
Host 192.168.199.15
Origin  null
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; …) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/58.0
```

I have been searching all over the Internet on how to solve this issue. 
Somebody please help. I Cannot change the printer firmware for the http server and can only do something from the Javascript I control.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 4):

You need to enable ePos Webservices.

This cannot be done using the executable utilities provided.
Once your printer is connected to the network with a valid local IP, you need to browse http://192.168.199.15 (or whatever your epson printer IP is) with your usual browser, it will ask you for user password which default to epson/epson OR epson/printer serialNb then you need to navigate to ePos print, and then enable the option ePos Print, finaly click the restart button just underneath.
Then the printer will add an Allow-Cross-Origin * header to the HTTP response headers, which is good, and no need to disable usefull browser feature.

Comment: Excellent ! I work perfect. I had not been able to resolve this problem for days, and even epson support did not help me

Comment: Correct answer. This isn't anywhere in espon documentation. Thanks!

Comment: Had this working and then this morning the printer "forgot"  and stopped adding the cors header -the  setting was still enabled however.  logging into the printer UI and providing the uid/pw resolved it but that was unexpected and now has me hunting a way to automate the login.  just fyi it may not be set and forget.

Comment: Don't see the option in my web page. Does that mean my printer does not support it? TM-L90

Comment: ePos Print was enabled by default in my case. However, I am still getting the CORS error.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to solve the CORS issue if you do not have control over the server.

Method 1.

Install the CORS plugin https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cors-toggle/jioikioepegflmdnbocfhgmpmopmjkim?hl=en

This would be useful if your application is made only for you and would not be used by anyone else. Also, some websites like youtube would stop working so use with caution

Method 2.

Create your own proxy server. Recommended but needs technical know how. This solution is especially useful if your application is used by lot of other users too. This is something I have done before and has worked well. You can host your proxy server on heroku or anywhere you want. Your proxy server would intercept the OPTIONS request and would send Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * in response headers thus enabling your browser to make a get/post call. Your proxy server would then route your request to the actual server and return the response from the actual server back to the client

Comment: Tried method 1 , doesn't bring a difference. Am I missing something? BTW, I have to deploy this solution on an android tablet with chrome/firefox for customers..

Comment: If this application is for customers, method 1 is not a good method to go for. Go for method 2.

Comment: any suggestions for a proxy on android tablet?

Comment: The device does not matter really. Your JS code would make a call to proxy server on which you have full control. This might be hosted on something like heroku or similar.

Comment: Im confused. The page is accessed on a device through firefox/chrome and how can I have a proxy there? Can you explain ?

Comment: When a page makes a request, instead of hitting the regular server, hit the proxy server. Proxy server is like a regular server but with a well defined purpose. Its only purpose in this case is to route requests from client to the server and send response from server to the client.

Comment: I got it but how to get this behaviour on a tablet

Comment: I do not understand. How does it matter if it is a tablet as long as you are running application on chrome/firefox? It should behave exactly the same way

Comment: you mean I run a proxy server on a tablet as an app or ?

Comment: Nope, proxy server hosted somewhere just like your normal server. All your calls would be made to this proxy server that would then reroute your calls to actual server

Comment: thats a problem. I communicate from tablet to printer at a restaurant and can't have a proxy there .. how about this? https://cors.io?http://192.168.99.15 such URL will work? I found that on https://cors.io